# why ping of domain show wrong IP

Tags: dns, ping

Why ping show wrong IP if real server is "84.xxx.xxx.186"

Domain: em.xxx.com

Sometimes IS is correct. How is this possible?
Page works normally, load a long time but works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the nslookup command:

```
nslookup em.xxx.com
```

We can see that this domain has actual 3 different IPS allocated:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    xxx.com
Addresses:  84.xxx.xxx.186
          208.109.255.6
          216.69.185.6
```

And my following ping actually contacted the third IP:

```
ping em.xxx.com

Pinging xxx.com [216.69.185.6] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.69.185.6: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=49
Reply from 216.69.185.6: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=49
Reply from 216.69.185.6: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=49
```

Both the other IPS seem to belong to GoDaddy, so they probably have some kind of DNS load balancing I would guess.